# How to write custom validator directive for model driven forms in Angular2?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-directives, angular2-services

I am new to Angular2

I red many articals to write custom validator directive for Model Driven Forms

But I am not understood properly?

Is there any good one to understood. I want email, passord,cpassrod validation in directive. and how to use directive in form

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Validator directives are for template drive forms. For model driven forms pass them to the controls like

```
this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    email:['', Validators.compose([
    Validators.required,
    Validators.pattern('.+@.+\..+'),
    ]), this.validators.isTaken],
```

See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormBuilder-class.html